# cntlm default config file ubuntu missing

Tags: ubuntu

I keep getting a cntlm: could not open default config file error when I run:

```
cntlm -v -I -M http://www.google.com
```

I have however configured both cntlm.conf files at:

/etc/cntlm.conf

&

/usr/local/etc/cntlm.conf

what is the problem?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an operating system/command line program issue, and is not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines. It may be better suited for either [ubuntu.se] or [su] instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed cntlm (via apt-get), you should have the cntlm conf file in the etc directory.  When you run the cntlm command, you need to pass in the cntlm.conf to the command:

```
cntlm /etc/cntlm.conf -v -I -M http://www.google.com
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It is giving error "Invalid proxy specification /etc/cntlm.conf"

Comment: @Sharique - you need to raise your own question with the relevant details, particularly for your proxy setup

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:
`cntlm -c /etc/cntlm.conf` and then the rest of the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo cntlm -v -I -M http://www.google.com
```

Just added "sudo" at the beginning and it worked for me.